# Merge clusters into lowest cluster

Tags: r

I hope what I'm asking about is very simple and my google foo is just poor.

Using st_intersects from sf package i have a table of each point and its intersecting points.

I'm trying to join these together as per the below example. What basic function am i missing? I could do this with a loop but it seems inefficient.

```
**Example:** 

df <- data.frame(
  Source = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
  Match = c(1,2,2,1,4,3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

print(df)

  Source Match
    1     1
    1     2
    2     2
    2     1
    2     4
    3     3


**Desired output:**

  Source Match
     1     1
     1     2
     1     4
     3     3
```

Because Match 2 is in Source 1 and 2 every Match from Source 2 has been moved to Source 1.

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);df %>% filter(!duplicated(Match))`

Comment: Hi @akrun Thanks for the suggestions sadly these just group by Source and don't merge the sources pots. I have added an additional row to try and make what  I'm after easier to understand.

Comment: @akrun Sorry if i'm not being clear.  I want to combine source 1 and source 2 into source 1 because source 1 contains a match in source 2. Source 3 is left as source 3 because it is in neither 1 or 2.

I've edited out the row ids to hopefully make it clearer.